# Multi-Tenant with multiple Database (A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to login in my application with a specific tenant that has its own database. And I always got this erro: *"A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*. How can I fix it?

I'm using AspNet Boilerplate MVC5.x  with an oracle sql database. 
I enabled multitenancy and I tried to login with a tenant that has its own database. I did some modifications to the framework and my current tenant creation page has no connectionString field to fill. So I created that field running the project in debug mode and generating the encrypted string for my connectionString. I tested the connectionString before and it works perfectly. Next I assign the result to **Tenant1** to the connectionString column. When I try to login with this tenant I got the error.

Following is the my DbContext code:

```
public MyProjectDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString): base(GetDbConnection(nameOrConnectionString), true)
{

}

public static DbConnection GetDbConnection(string companyName)
{
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = null;
      if (companyName.ToUpper().Contains("USER ID") && companyName.ToUpper().Contains("PASSWORD"))
      {
          builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(companyName);
      }
      else
      {
          builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[companyName].ConnectionString);
      }

      DbConnection serviceDiscoveryDbConnection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client").CreateConnection();
      serviceDiscoveryDbConnection.ConnectionString = GetOracleManagedConnectionString(builder.DataSource, builder.UserID, builder.Password);

      return serviceDiscoveryDbConnection;
}
```

I already tried an AspNetBoilerplate [sample](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) and I changed it to use mysql. However when I try to create a tenant with a connectionString filled I got the following error: *"Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported."*. In my opinion this is a similar error. So, I think the solution should be almost the same for both problems. Even when I add manually the connectionString to the mysql database I got the same error when I try to do the login.

What I want is to have a multi-db/multi-tenant where each tenant has its own database. So if I do login with **Tenant2/myuser**, when I enter in home page, I want to do all the calls to the **Tenant2** correspondent database.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: On which line is it throwing the exception?

Comment: In my project I got the error when I try to do login (_logInManager.LoginAsync in GetLoginResultAsync). In sample I got the error in TenantAppService->Create->CreateStaticRoles line 73.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fresh template?

Comment: you're creating your own `DbConnection` which I guess breaking the `UnitOfWork` concept. Disable `UnitOfWork` on login method to see if that's the case. To disable `UnitOfWork` add `[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]` attribute to the method. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#unit-of-work-in-detail

Comment: I'm using a fresh template, I just changed to mysql according to this link https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-MySql-Integration

Comment: I also tested with UnitOfWork disabled but I still get the same error

Comment: Ok, I tested the sample with sql server (just like a fresh template) and the error in the sample is gone. So, my question is, am I doing the oracle sql connection right?

Comment: I already fixed my oracle sql connection (now it's equal to the sample). However I still get the error. Any help pls